# Synchronized version of System.Collections.Generic.SortedList?

Tags: c#, .net

I need a thread-safe version of a `SortedList<T,U>`, but unlike its [generic form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) the [non-generic form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) doesn't appear to have [`Synchronized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.synchronized.aspx) functionality. Is there a different trick I can use to get a thread-safe version? Or will I have to resort to using `lock (SyncRoot)` manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: no you have to resort `lock`.

Even if in the new namespace `System.Collections.Concurrent` you have thread safe collections the thread safe version of `SortedList<T, U>` isn't there.
If you need a to protect each call to `SortedList<T, U>` with a `lock` or a `ReadWriterLockSlim` (when applicable) or, in alternative, to create a thread safe wrapper for `SortedList<T, U>` (in the same way `Synchronized()` does).

**Longer answer**: no you do not have anything ready but you can achieve the same result using together `OrderablePartitioner<TSource>` (to extract one item per time) and `ConcurrentBag<T>`. Frankly speaking I don't know if there is any ROI with this strategy because if you do not need a partitioner then you simply add complexity to something shouldn't be.